# Why does unused file fields are having blank value?

Tags: eval, ibm-midrange, rpg

I have a table named

> EQRECORDS

as below-

```
 A          R REQ                                                                                              
  A            FNAME         10A                                                                                  
  A            LNAME         10A                                                                                  
  A          K FNAME
```

and program as below-

```
fEQRECORDS if   e           k disk                
d uwvar2          s             10a   inz('ANKUR')
 /free                                            
  setll *loval req;                               
  reade uwvar2 req;                               
  dow not %eof(eqrecords) and not %error;         
    dsply lname;                                  
    reade uwvar2 req;                             
  enddo;                                          
  *inlr = *on;                                    
 /end-free
```

When first time READE executes, if I want to see the value of Fname using Eval. Why is it shown Blank?

Data in the table is as below-

```
**FNAME       LNAME** 
VIKASH      SHUKLA
VIKASH      SHUKLA
ANKUR       VERMA 
ANKUR       MEHTA 
VIKASH      MISHRA
VIKASH      GUPTA 
ANKUR       GUPTA 
BHASKAR     MISHRA
CHINTU            
BHUVI       GUPTA
```

Comment: Is there an actual value in the field? Try running a query against the table with no ordering to see what the first result is.

Comment: Yes Fname has value.

Comment: My RPG is getting rusty. I can't remember if, when using a data structure, you need to use use the dot notation. `req.lname`

Comment: I am getting an error "Identifier does not exist" while using req.lname. And want to see the value of Fname not of Lname as I am displaying Lname using Dsply opcode.

Comment: It's a simple performance item. If a field is not used by the program, then the value is not moved from the I/O buffer into program memory. The value is not "blank"; it `does not exist` in program memory. The compiler doesn't create an area for fields that aren't used. The effect is much more evident when a record has dozens of unreferenced fields and there are a million records.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using 'eval' in the debugger.  If you have OPTION(*NOUNREF) on an H-spec or the compile command then unreferenced fields are not available in the debugger.  Put OPTION(*UNREF) in your H-spec to have them be included.

Answer (score 0):

Post the exact code that is giving you the problem.  This should work:

```
 fEQRECORDS if   e           k disk
 d uwvar2          s             10a   inz('ANKUR')
 d message         s             50a   inz
  /free
   setll *loval req;
   reade uwvar2 req;
   dow not %eof(eqrecords) and not %error;
     message = %trimr(fname) + ' ' + lname;
     dsply message;
     reade uwvar2 req;
   enddo;
   *inlr = *on;
  /end-free
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this problem. I used debug(*input) in H-spec and got the result.

Try this link...
[Descreption about debug(*input)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/books_web/c0925086247.htm)